# Count occurrence of factors and sum them up in both rows and columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this table:

```
smoke <- matrix(c("one"," ","three","four "," "," ",
              " ","two","three","four"," ","Other",
              "one"," ","three","four"," "," ",
              " "," "," "," ","none"," ",
              " "," "," "," "," "," ",
              "  "," ","three","four"," ","Other",
              " "," "," "," ","none"," "
 ),ncol=6,byrow=TRUE)
colnames(smoke) <- c("Var_1","Var_2", "Var_3","Var_4","None","Other")
rownames(smoke) <- c(1,2,3,4," ",6,7)
```

smoke:

```
      Var_1  Var_2   Var_3    Var_4   None   Other  

  1    one           three     four 
  2           two    three     four          Other
  3    one           three     four
  4                                   None

  6                  three     four          Other
  7                                   None
```

Now I would like:

1. Remove the empty rows (e.g. row 5). The dataset has too many rows that I could detect empty rows easily.
2. Count the occurrence in both rows and columns. As you may noticed, the strings(variables) in each column are the same. i.e. same name, same length. However, the value in column "none" should be treated as 0 in column sums.

Here is the result I want:

```
        Var_1   Var_2    Var_3     Var_4     None    Other   col_sum

 1      one              three     four                          3
 2              two      three     four              Other       4
 3      one              three     four                          3
 4                                           None                0
 5                       three     four              Other       3
 6                                           None                0
 rowSum  2       1         4        4         2         2
```

I have learned how to handle the similar problem if those are numerical data. But now, I 'm not sure how to solve it. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `trimws` on the `matrix`, and count the non-blank with `rowSums` on a logical matrix

```
# // trim out the leading/lagging spaces
smoke <- trimws(smoke)
# // subset the rows by removing rows having only blank
smoke1 <- smoke[!!rowSums(smoke != ""),]
# // get the count of non-blank, non-none elements
rowSums(smoke1 != "" & smoke1 != "none")
#1 2 3 4 6 7 
#3 4 3 0 3 0
#// and with columns, use `colSums`
colSums(smoke1 != "")
#  Var_1 Var_2 Var_3 Var_4  None Other 
#    2     1     4     4     2     2
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try `marginSums` like below as well

```
> marginSums(smoke != " ", 1)
1 2 3 4   6 7
3 4 3 1 0 4 1

> marginSums(smoke != " ", 2)
Var_1 Var_2 Var_3 Var_4  None Other
    3     1     4     4     2     2
```

Comment: Thanks ThomaslsCoding.  A really nice solution. I tried addmargins and got error.  Now I know it should be marginSums. Thank you. But this time I will accept @akrun's answer as his came first :)

Comment: BTW, @ThomaslsCoding, what do you mean 1 in this case (smoke != " ", 1) and 2 ((smoke != " ", 2)?

Comment: @almo `1` or `2` represents the margin, e.g., by rows or columns

Comment: Thanks @ThomaslsCoding, I also tried out on R studio just. Also, I have found that the none value was calculated in column sum. That one I need to treat as 0. Otherwise, this solution is pretty. Thank you!